# Turning a list of dictionaries into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I know this is possible with list comprehension but I can't seem to figure it out. Currently I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
 [ {'field1': 'a', 'field2': 'b'},
   {'field1': 'c', 'field2': 'd'},
   {'field1': 'e', 'field2': 'f'} ]
```

I'm trying to turn this into:

```
list = [
    ['b', 'a'],
    ['d', 'c'],
    ['f', 'e'],
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
[[x['field2'], x['field1']] for x in l]
```

where `l` is your input list. The result for your data would be:

```
[['b', 'a'], ['d', 'c'], ['f', 'e']]
```

This way you ensure that the value for `field2` comes before the value for `field1`

Answer (score 4):

Just return the `dict.values()` lists in Python 2, or convert the dictionary view to a list in Python 3:

```
[d.values() for d in list_of_dicts]  # Python 2
[list(d.values()) for d in list_of_dicts]  # Python 3
```

Note that the values are not going to be in any specific order, because dictionaries are not ordered. If you expected them to be in a given order you'd have to add a sorting step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ordering you want, but for no order you could do:

```
list_ = [list(_.values()) for _ in dict_list]
```

Comment: Note that the `list()` call is only needed for Python 3, in Python 2 `dict.values()` returns a list already.

Comment: Well, it's not going to break anything so who cares.

Comment: If this is on a critical path you may care.

Comment: If it's on a critical path then he should figure out how to get the data in the right form in the first place. I guarantee that stepping through the data to generate the list is going to take WAY longer then shallow copying the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Python 3

```
>>>listdict = [ {'field1': 'a', 'field2': 'b'},
...             {'field1': 'c', 'field2': 'd'},
...             {'field1': 'e', 'field2': 'f'} ]

>>>[[a for a in dict.values()] for dict in listdict]
[['b', 'a'], ['d', 'c'], ['f', 'e']]
```

Python 2

```
>>>[dict.values() for dict in listdict]
[['b', 'a'], ['d', 'c'], ['f', 'e']]
```