# Python: Convert list of coordinates and remove characters

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have extracted gps coordinates from a gpx file in a list looking like this:

```
[{'lat': '51.604443', 'lon': '7.205795'}, {'lat': '51.604390', 'lon': '7.205635'}]
```

For further calculations, those coordinates have to be converted to a list looking like this:

```
[51.604443, 7.205795, 51.60439, 7.205635]
```

... and to create polylines with iplyleaflet they have to look like this:

```
[51.604443, 7.205795],
[51.60439, 7.205635],
```

Edit: This has been already answered here: 
[Turning a list of dictionaries into a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627141/turning-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-a-list-of-lists)

My first question is diffferent though, I suppose.

I have been working on this issue for hours. I have tried to use list comprehension, but the problem is that it the upper list seems to be a list of dicts and I do not know how to convert them to items in a list. I am new to python so it would be really great if someone could give me some tips. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: `[[d['lat'], d['lon']] for d in my_list]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two goals here. You need a single list with all datapoints, and you need a list of lists containing pairs of datapoints.

1. For your first goal, just loop through the dicts and append both values to a single list.

```
all_values = []
for dict in my_list:
  all_values.append(dict['lat'])
  all_values.append(dict['long'])
```

2. As was mentioned in the comments, you can achieve your second goal very easily by turning the list of dictionaries into a list of lists. You can do this similar to what we did above, but in a single simple line.

`list_of_pairs = [[dict['lat'], dict['lon']] for dict in my_list]`

And that's it! Now you've got both of the lists that you need.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! You made my day! I should have tried the obvious approach before starting to read into list comprehension and regex.